# Angular 2 getting error **CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory** while using npm run start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-run

Angular2 i am getting this error **CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory** while running using **npm run start**

i have tried upgrading the npm version, also i have tired increasing --max_old_space_size=4096

<--- Last few GCs --->

260217 ms: Mark-sweep 1360.9 (1437.1) -> 1360.1 (1437.1) MB, 4457.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  264705 ms: Mark-sweep 1360.1 (1437.1) -> 1360.1 (1437.1) MB, 4487.6 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  269354 ms: Mark-sweep 1360.1 (1437.1) -> 1372.9 (1418.1) MB, 4647.6 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  274068 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.9 (1418.1) -> 1385.8 (1418.1) MB, 4713.5 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000003CA3933FA99 
    1: emitPos [D:\Projects\PremierX\premierx\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~61863] [pc=0000008C600372C9] (this=0000033E1F336D41 ,pos=1372571)
    2: emitNodeWithSourceMap [D:\Projects\PremierX\premierx\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~61912] [pc=0000008C60022A38] (this=0000033E1F336D41 ,hint=3,node=0000032F08950D4
9

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! premierx@0.0.0 prestart: `ng build --prod && ngc && webpack --max_old_space_size=8092`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the premierx@0.0.0 prestart script 'ng build --prod && ngc && webpack --max_old_space_size=8092'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the premierx package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng build --prod && ngc && webpack --max_old_space_size=8092
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs premierx
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls premierx
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\PremierX\premierx\npm-debug.log

Any solutions for this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any Solution you got ?